# change url in codeigniter like controller

Tags: codeigniter, url, segment

I have a form which is sending data to another controller with **GET** method.
when i submitted the form, the url become like this ;

http://localhost/bb/sloome/?decision=unknown&modals=infox&_modal=kaleme

but ı want it to be like this

http://localhost/bb/sloome/kaleme

is it possible in codeigniter ?

Comment: If you send it by GET method, the URL is going to change. Would you prefer a POST to /kaleme? That's possible.

Comment: For URL if you want it like this `http://localhost/bb/sloome/kaleme` then it follows the rules `http://localhost/bb/project-folder-name/controller/function`

Answer (score 0):

you can pass url in your js file.like this.i hope it will help you.

document.location.href="sloome.php?=" + kaleme;